# These two questions are not duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

These two questions

- [Question you really want to ask AS a potential EMPLOYER but cannot?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53167/question-you-really-want-to-ask-as-a-potential-employer-but-cannot)
- [Question you really want to ask AS a potential EMPLOYEE but cannot?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53158/question-you-really-want-to-ask-as-a-potential-employee-but-cannot)

are obviously related, but not duplicates. Rather, they are opposing pairs.

IMHO it was a mistake to merge them as duplicates and close the latter one. Now, most of the answers associated with the former one aren't actually valid answers to that question. (I even downvoted these mistakenly, before noticing that they have been merged from the other thread.)

Of course, it is another issue whether this pair of posts is suitable at PSE. To me it is borderline, I wouldn't object them getting closed as off topic. But merging them only created confusion.

Comment: Agreed, now you have one very confusing thread of answers.

Comment: Doesn't matter anyway.  Neither of those questions met the guidelines in the FAQ for something you should ask here.

Comment: @jmort253, do you mean that one can do _anything_ with questions not meeting the guidelines in the FAQ? IMHO they should still be closed as off topic, plain and simple.

Comment: that's fair enough but as a closed question it's likely to end up being deleted so it's not really a major deal what the close reason was is it?

Comment: @Jon, I don't care much about the concrete questions here. I only wanted to give feedback about what I see as a careless moderator action, in the hope that it will help avoiding similar issues in the future. I hope I don't sound offensive or personal towards the moderators, that was not my intention.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that they're not duplicates. I imagine the similarity in titles (there's only a 1 letter difference) made it seem like they're pretty much the same. Unfortunately question merges aren't reversibl, but I edited the remaining question to add "employee" into its scope.

That said, I don't think either of them is a good question for this site. Neither is programmer-specific or constructive as defined by the guidelines in our FAQ.